# Selecting data for columns based on a range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has a week_id and net_sales for that week (as well as a lot of other columns).

```
style_number, week_id, net_sales
ABCD, 1, 100.00
ABCD, 2, 125.00
EFGH, 1,  50.00
EFGH, 2,  75.00
```

I am trying to write a statement that will list the

```
style_number, net_sales
```

for the

```
MAX(week_id), net_sales for the MAX(week_id)-1 .... , MAX(week_id) - n
```

So that the results look like:

```
ABCD, 125.00, 100.00
EFGH,  75.00,  50.00
```

What is the best way to approach this, especially when n can be rather large (i.e. looking back 52 weeks)?

I hope this makes sense!  I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.  Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Could you be okay with the net sales just being a comma separated list?

Comment: So....you want as many columns as there are weeks on some of your style_nymbers?

Comment: @wilsjd - possibly would that be a lot easier to do?

Comment: @Lamak Kind of...I think that I will always be using either 26 weeks or 52 weeks, but there could exist way more than that depending on how many weeks of data there is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIVOT` and dynamic SQL to deal with your large number of weeks

```sql
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(week_id)
            FROM sales
            ORDER BY 1 DESC
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @sql = 'SELECT style_number, ' + @cols +   
           '  FROM 
            (
              SELECT style_number, week_id, net_sales
                FROM sales
            ) x
            PIVOT 
            (
               MAX(net_sales) FOR week_id IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY style_number'

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b967c/1)** demo.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the `PIVOT` command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

**OR**

If you are okay with the result being a comma separated list, you could use the `STUFF` and `FOR XML` commands like so.

```
SELECT DISTINCT      
         style_name,

         STUFF(
               (SELECT  ',' + CAST(net_sales AS VARCHAR(20))
               FROM      MyTable AS SubTable
               WHERE      SubTableUser.style = MyTable.style_name
               ORDER BY   week_id DESC --DESC will get your max ID to be first
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS net_sales_list

FROM      MyTable
ORDER BY style_name
```

This will provide you with:

```
style_name | net_sales_list
---------------------------
ABCD       | 100.00,125.00
EFGH       | 75.00,50.00
```

Comment: I was reading about that in "Micrsoft SQL Server 2012 - TSQL Fundamentals" and it sounds like it might work, but I haven't been able to get it to work.  If this is the best way to go, I will probably just take the time to really absorb the material before trying to write again.

Comment: Look at @peterm's answer, that is one way to get it to work. The thing with `PIVOT` is that you have to specify the columns. The dynamic SQL will get you there.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of weeks, since you are using SQL Server 2008, you can use the `PIVOT` command, or you can use `MAX` with `CASE`:

Here's an example using `MAX` with `CASE`:

```
select 
   style_number, 
   max(case when week_id = 2 then net_sales end) week2sales,
   max(case when week_id = 1 then net_sales end) week1sales
from yourtable
group by style_number
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a92b/1)

If you do not know the number of weeks, you'll need to look into using dynamic SQL.  Just do a search, lots of posts on SO on it.